# Reusable component data render using switch case

Tags: reactjs, children

I have a reusable component that mimics a button function. I need to display four different types of content based on FAQ value, from my reusable child component 'CustomButton' back to parent component.

`CustomButton.js`

```
const CustomButton = (props) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        switch(props.faq){
            case 'general':
                return 'div 1';
            case 'payment':
                return 'div 2';
            case 'business':
                return 'div 3';
            case 'online':
                return 'div 4';
        }
    }
        return (
                <div>
                    {React.cloneElement(props.children, {onClick: handleClick})}
                </div>
        )
}

export default CustomButton
```

`Faq.js`

```
export default class Faq extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="set_faq">
                <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
                    <CustomButton faq={'general'}><button>General FAQ</button></CustomButton>
                    <CustomButton faq={'payment'}><button>Payment FAQs</button></CustomButton>
                    <CustomButton faq={'business'}><button>Business FAQs</button></CustomButton>
                    <CustomButton faq={'online'}><button>Online Sellers</button></CustomButton>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {/* to display content here based on div clicked */}
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I am unable to handle the result returned by switch statement back to the CustomButton file to render the data. Kindly help to complete the work around.

Comment: your CustomButton cannot re-used because you are hardcode that CustomButton only handle 4 case words. If has any case, you have to change code in CustomButton, so that's not called component reusable. My opinion, add onClick prop for CustomButton and handle it in the parent component which call the CustomButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to lift the state up and manage the value clicked direclty inside the `Faq` component instead of `CustomButton`. This way, you can manage a unique state and display what you need to display accordingly.

The `CustomButton` is simplified:

```
const CustomButton = props => {
  return <div onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

And `App` component now manages a state and the `handleClick` function which now saves the `faq` clicked in a state. This way you can render the data based on what was clicked

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { clickedValue: "" };

  handleClick = faq => ev => {
    switch (faq) {
      case "general":
        this.setState({ clickedValue: "div 1" });
        break;
      case "payment":
        this.setState({ clickedValue: "div 2" });
        break;
      case "business":
        this.setState({ clickedValue: "div 3" });
        break;
      case "online":
        this.setState({ clickedValue: "div 4" });
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="set_faq">
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-around"
          }}
        >
          <CustomButton handleClick={this.handleClick("general")}>
            <button>General FAQ</button>
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton handleClick={this.handleClick("payment")}>
            <button>Payment FAQs</button>
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton handleClick={this.handleClick("business")}>
            <button>Business FAQs</button>
          </CustomButton>
          <CustomButton handleClick={this.handleClick("online")}>
            <button>Online Sellers</button>
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
        <div>{this.state.clickedValue}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-yalow-bvgbe

PS: I tried to limit modifications on your code to resolve your issue however, it's not the best HTML markup to have a `button` inside a `div` which captures the `onClick` event.